# How to mix formatting in a single call using libfmt

Tags: c++, stdstring, fmt

I want to print the time center aligned. But I do not know how to mix arguments with fmt.

```
std::cout << fmt::format("|{0: ^80}|\n", "");
std::cout << fmt::format("|{0:%c}|\n", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
```

This prints:

```
|                                                                                |
|Fri May 13 09:24:05 2022|
```

I tried the followin but the program crasches:

```
std::cout << fmt::format("|{0:%c{:^ 80}}|\n", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
```

How can I print the date string center aligned?

A solution I found is to pass another format:

```
std::cout << fmt::format("|{0: ^80}|\n",
                 fmt::format("{0:%c}", std::chrono::system_clock::now()));
```

But this does not look good? I think there should be a way to do it in just one format?

Comment: Looks like a bug... Better to submit an new issue on github.

Comment: Send Victor&friends a message if it's a bug. https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues

Answer (score 1):

From https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html :

```
chrono_format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][width]["." precision][chrono_specs]
```

Just:

```
fmt::format("|{0: ^80%c}|\n", ....
```

Comment: Unfortunately it prints a literal `" ^80"` before the data-time string ([see here](https://godbolt.org/z/K3feY4eEP)). It seems chrono formats doesn't really work exactly the same as other formats.

Comment: Hm... I wonder if it's a bug in the library or specification.